# Why am I getting a parsing error in NDSolveValue?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am not sure why I am getting a `PDE parsing error of {Inactive[Div][{{<<2>>}, {-<<9>>Y, <<1>>}} . \ <<1>>] == 0}. Inconsistent equation dimensions` in the code below.

All that is happening in the code below is that the first NDSolve solves for a potential given some coefficients. This gives the correct solution. I add a tiny change to that interpolation function and attempt to solve the inverse problem of finding the coefficients and get a parsing error.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

nl = 40 ;
n1 = 2 ;
rpn = 0.6 ;
delta = 0.0 ;
w = 0.2;
r0 = rpn + delta + w ;
r1 = rpn - delta  - w ;
a = Solve[n1 == nl (1 - a/r0^3), a][[1]][[1]][[2]];
N1 = 40 (1 - a/r^3);
N2 = 2;
(*N3= (2/delta) (r - rpn) ;*)
N4  = -2 ; 
beta1 = Solve[1 - 1/beta == 5 (1 - 1/(r1^2 + beta^2)^((1/2))), 
      beta ][[3]][[1]][[2]];
gamma = (-10)/(1 - 1/beta1);
N5 = gamma (1 - 1/Sqrt[r^2 + beta1^2]);

micrometer = 1;
centimeter = micrometer 10^4;
hbar = 10^-27 centimeter^2;
vfermi = 10^8 centimeter ;
volt = 10^4  centimeter^2;
meV = 1.6 10^-15  centimeter^2;
gauss = 1 ;
tesla = 10^4 gauss ;
nP =  (10^12)/centimeter^2;
nN = 0.76^2  nP; 
a = 0.5; 
Lx = 15; Ly = 15;
beta = 1;
rad = a Sqrt[(-1 + (1 + nN/nP)^(2/3))];
Plot[nl ( 1 +  ((-nP - nN)/nP)/(1 + r^2/ (a^2))^(beta/2)), {r, 0, 5}]

omegactimestau[B_] := 4.8 10^-10 B/(1.7 10^-29 3 10^10) 3 10^-4/10^8;
\[Sigma]xx = 10^-6 + Piecewise[{
     {Abs[N5 + 2], 0 <= r <= r1  },
     {0 , r1 <= r <= rpn - delta},
     {0, rpn - delta <= r <= rpn + delta},
     {0 , rpn + delta <= r <= r0},
     {N1 - 2, r >= r0}
     }];
\[Sigma]xy = nl ( 1 +  ((-nP - nN)/nP)/(1 + r^2/ (a^2))^(beta/2));
sigmaxxcheck[x_, y_, B_] := 
 1/omegactimestau[B] \[Sigma]xx /. {r -> 
    Sqrt[(x - Lx/2)^2 + (y - Ly/2)^2]}
sigmaxycheck[x_, y_, 
  B_] := \[Sigma]xy /. {r -> Sqrt[(x - Lx/2)^2 + (y - Ly/2)^2]}


<< NDSolve`FEM`
rectangle = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= Lx && 0 <= y <= Ly, {x, y}];
frefine = 
  Function[{vertices, area}, Block[{x1, y1}, {x1, y1} = Mean[vertices];
    If[(x1 - Lx/2)^2 + (y1 - Ly/2)^2 < 2 && area > 0.0005, True, 
     False]]];
mesh = ToElementMesh[rectangle, MaxBoundaryCellMeasure -> 10^-3, 
   MeshRefinementFunction -> frefine];

reg = mesh;

brange = Range[0.5, 2, 0.5]*tesla; sol = 
 NDSolveValue[{Inactive[
        Div][{{sigmaxxcheck[x, y, #], 
          sigmaxycheck[x, y, #]}, {-sigmaxycheck[x, y, #], 
          sigmaxxcheck[x, y, #]}} . 
        Inactive[Grad][phi[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == 0, 
     phi[Lx, y] == 1, phi[0, y] == -1}, 
    phi, {x, y} \[Element] reg] & /@ brange;


R1 = 0.5 ; R2 = 0.75 ; Rm = 1/2 (R1 + R2); w0 = 0.005;
Plot[0.04 Exp[-1/(2 w0) (r - Rm)^2], {r, 0, 1.5}, PlotRange -> All]
fn = sol[Lx/2, x + Ly/2] /. sol -> sol[[2]] ;
Plot[fn + 
  0.08 (Exp[-1/(2 w0) (x - Rm)^2] + 
     Exp[-1/(2 w0) (x + Rm)^2]), {x, -2, 2}]



PhiOld[x_, y_] := sol[x + Lx/2, y + Ly/2] /. sol -> sol[[2]]

BumpPhi[x_, y_] := 
 0.08 (Exp[-1/(2 w0) (r - Rm)^2] + Exp[-1/(2 w0) (r - Rm)^2]) /. {r ->
     Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}
PhiNew[x_, y_] := PhiOld[x, y] + BumpPhi[x, y]


rectangle = ImplicitRegion[-5 <= x <= 5 && -5 <= y <= 5, {x, y}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[rectangle, MaxBoundaryCellMeasure -> 10^-3];
reg = mesh;
solSigma = 
  NDSolveValue[{Inactive[
       Div][{{10^-4, SigmaNewXY[x, y]}, {-SigmaNewXY[x, y], 10^-4}} . 
       Inactive[Grad][PhiNew[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == 0, 
    SigmaNewXY[5, y] == 30, SigmaNewXY[-5, y] == 30}, 
   SigmaNewXY, {x, y} \[Element] reg];
```

The details of the problem although unimportant are in [Why does NDSolve solution not match physical intuition?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287047/why-does-ndsolve-solution-not-match-physical-intuition)

EDIT :

I can understand if a solution does not converge in this case because the equation is hyperbolic. But if I give it some diffusion coefficient in fact the very same used in the first NDSolve it still gives the parser error. In the code below I have replaced the diagonal coefficient in the second NDSolve to the same coefficient used in the first NDSolve.

```
sigmaxx1[x_, y_] := 
 1/omegactimestau[1 tesla] \[Sigma]xx /. {r -> Sqrt[(x)^2 + (y)^2]}



solSigma = 
  NDSolveValue[{Inactive[
       Div][{{sigmaxx1[x, y], SigmaNewXY[x, y]}, {-SigmaNewXY[x, y], 
         sigmaxx1[x, y]}} . Inactive[Grad][PhiNew[x, y], {x, y}], {x, 
       y}] == 0, SigmaNewXY[5, y] == 30, SigmaNewXY[-5, y] == 30}, 
   SigmaNewXY, {x, y} \[Element] reg];
```

EDIT 2:

This is very surprising to me.

In an attempt to see what is happening, I tried solving the inverse problem for the solution of phi obtained from the first NDSolve which no change to the interpolation function obtained from it and it still gives me a parsing error.

Comment: Without `Inactive[]` in both `NDSolve`- commands your code evaluates!

Comment: It tells me the equation is hyperbolic and gives a warning and does not run.

Comment: Also if I remove Inactive I get the wrong answer for the first NDSolve

Comment: Mathematica v12.2 gives no warning messages

Comment: I wish people would put ``ClearAll["Global`*"]`` in their code blocks.

Comment: When I try this I get a different error: LinearSolve::parpiv: Zero pivot was detected during the numerical factorization or there was a problem in the iterative refinement process. It is possible that the matrix is ill-conditioned or singular.

Comment: I suggest you simplify the example to a single case, such that we can look at the parsing issue.

Comment: @user21 How should I simplify the problem ?

Comment: 1) Remove the mesh refinement stuff, and see if you still get the error message. In that case it can go, because it is not related to the issue. Then the code runs much faster. 2) `SigmaNewXY[x, y]` does not seem to be defined,